# Save exe output to text file realtime

Tags: c++, windows, exe, minecraft

I have an exe file that connects to a server and outputs results in realtime. Is there any way, using windows, I can store the result of this exe output to a text file, with it updating in semi-realtime? I've tried `example.exe > log.txt`, but it returns

```
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32 left, Int32 top)
   at MinecraftClient.ConsoleIO.Write(String text)
   at MinecraftClient.ConsoleIO.WriteLine(String line)
   at MinecraftClient.McTcpClient.OnConnectionLost(DisconnectReason reason, String message)
   at MinecraftClient.Protocol.Handlers.Protocol18Handler.Updater()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: What does it do without the redirection? Does anything in your program try to write to "log.txt" as well? Perhaps try with a different unique name.

Comment: To me, the error seems to indicate that the program requires that its output device is some sort of controllable (console) device. `SetCursorPosition` isn't something one should try on a plain file. You could possibly find a program that fakes a console to use as a filter between `example.exe` and your redirect: `example.exe | fakeconsole.exe > log.txt` - but since `example.exe` moves the cursor around, I'm not sure what to expect in the output.

Comment: Interesting input. Do you know how/where I could find a program that might do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
mycommand.exe param 2>&1 > myfile.txt
```

And it will create the `myfile.txt` at startup and fill it.

The `2` correspond to error log, and `&1` add basic log (not debug).

[More informations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/cpp/redirecting-error-command-prompt)